# How to abort an XHR connection when there are multiple running simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm working on a file uploader, where about 10 files upload at the same time via a for loop.

Now I am trying to create a cancel button to cancel **ALL** the uploads, however with my current code, **only the very last upload will cancel**.

I've included my boiled down code, but basically its a loop which goes through an array of images (theAttach) and for each image it sets up an xhrAttach to send the images.  So about say 10 images start uploading at the same time.

If a cancel button is pressed, I run the command **xhrAttach.abort();** but only the very last image aborts.

Any ideas?

```
                for (var i=0;i<theAttach.length;i++)
                { 

                    var xhrAttach = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
                        xhrAttach.timeout = 15000;
                        xhrAttach.onsendstream = function(e){


                        };

                        xhrAttach.onreadystatechange = function() {

                            if (xhrAttach.readyState != 4) return;

                                    if ((i == theAttach.length) && (xhrAttach.readyState == 4))
                                    {               

                                    }           

                        };

                        xhrAttach.onerror = function() {
                        };


                            xhrAttach.open('POST', url, true);
                            xhrAttach.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', theuseragent());           
                            xhrAttach.send(AttachmentTransmitArray);        

                }
```

Comment: There is an abort() method. http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort()-method

Comment: you need to cache each of your xhr into an array... then loop through them with  something like xhrAttach[i].abort().in your code you overwrite xhrAttach every time, thats why the last one you create is the only one you can abort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocco nailed it!  He suggested I cache each xhr into a container array, therefore I could access the individual xhr and abort it that way ie `xhrAttach[i].abort()`

I did this and it works perfectly!  Thanks cocco!

Comment: can you provide me example